# How to filter a struct array in a spark dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I have the following code and outputs.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{collect_list, struct}
import sqlContext.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  ("john", "tomato", 1.99),
  ("john", "carrot", 0.45),
  ("bill", "apple", 0.99),
  ("john", "banana", 1.29),
  ("bill", "taco", 2.59)
).toDF("name", "food", "price")

df.groupBy($"name")
  .agg(collect_list(struct($"food", $"price")).as("foods"))
  .show(false)

df.printSchema
```

Output and Schema:

```
+----+---------------------------------------------+
|name|foods                                        |
+----+---------------------------------------------+
|john|[[tomato,1.99], [carrot,0.45], [banana,1.29]]|
|bill|[[apple,0.99], [taco,2.59]]                  |
+----+---------------------------------------------+

root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- foods: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- food: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- price: double (nullable = false)
```

I want to filter based on df("foods.price") > 1.00. How do I filter this to get the output below?

```
+----+---------------------------------------------+
|name|foods                                        |
+----+---------------------------------------------+
|john|[[banana,1.29], [tomato,1.99]]               |
|bill|[[[taco,2.59]]                               |
+----+---------------------------------------------+
```

I have tried `df.filter($"foods.food" > 1.00)`, but this does not work as I'm getting an error. Anything else I can try?

Comment: Should the filter be moved up on to the df itself.

Comment: Not following. Could you give the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are trying to apply filter on an array, hence it will throw an error as the syntax will be wrong. You can apply filter on price before and then do transformation as needed.

```
val cf = df.filter("price > 1.0").groupBy($"name").agg(collect_list(struct($"food", $"price")).as("foods")
```

[image]